# Free Dynamically Allocated Array C

Tags: c, dynamic, malloc, std

I am in a bit of dilemma, thus, first of all I would like to apologize of if the next questions will be a bit more noobish or if they have been asked before (I couldn't find the answers for those though).

Anyway, I will explain it by giving a task as an example (it's not homework, it's just for the sake of my question). Here it goes:

```
Given a string from stdin index each word, then print each word on one line.
Example:
str[] = "Stack is awesome"
str_index {
    [0] => "Stack"
    [1] => "is"
    [2] => "awesome"
}
```

I know that there are many ways to solve this, but, again, for the sake of my question

Bare this solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/* fgets adds an unwanted '\n' at the end, so I made
 * a special function to read from stdin that removes
 * that '\n'.
 */
int read(char *str, int size) {
    // fgets adds an unwanted '\n' at the end, so we remove it
    fgets(str, size, stdin);

    int length = strlen(str);
    str[length - 1] = '\0';

    return length;
}

/* A function that breaks a string into words, indexes them
 * and prints them out, all done dynamically with malloc.
 */
void str_index(char *str) {
    char **index, *ptr;
    int i = 0, number_of_words;

    index = malloc(sizeof(char *));

    ptr = strtok(str, " ");
    for(i = 0; ptr != NULL; i++) {
        index = realloc(index, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        index[i] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(index[i], ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    number_of_words = i;

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_words; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", index[i]);
    }

    return;
}

int main() {
    char str[250];
    read(str, 250);
    str_index(str);

return 0;
```

}

**QUESTIONS**

1. Where do I have to free the arrays that I have allocated dynamically
   in str_index?
2. Do we have to free them within the function str_index? If so, why?
   What I know is that when a function is done executing all local
   variables are destroyed.
3. Why do we have to free them in main? Isn't main a function aswell,
   thus upon finishing executing it all variables defined in that function are destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are doing a university course. The problem (in my opinion) with university courses is that they start by teaching high level languages where everything is done magically, and then teach you a low level language. If I ruled the world, everyone would start with assembler, then C, then be allowed to 'progress' to Java etc.

To your question, the problem you have is the assumption that 'things might be done magically'. C doesn't do very much magically at all. In particular, if you `malloc()` or `calloc()` anything, or allocate anything using something that uses the heap allocator (for instance `strdup()`), it's your responsibility to free it. And you will need to do that explicitly. If you don't, you will have a memory leak. The first order problem is thus 'if I allocated it, I must ensure it is freed'. The second order problem is 'if I used a library that might have allocated stuff, I need to work out how to ensure it knows I've done, so it can free stuff'. If you bear this in mind, your C programming life will be happy, and `valgrind` will be your friend.

Let's now consider your questions:

1. You ask where you should free your dynamically allocated memory. Technically, in this example, you don't need to, because exiting your program will free all memory on the heap. However, let's suppose you want to use this function repeatedly. You want to free the allocation as soon as you no longer have a use for it. In the example presented, that would be immediately before the `return`. If you had other exits from the function, then make sure you free your allocation before every `return`. A useful error handling hint is to exit via the same code, and whenever you `free()` the allocation, also set the pointer to the allocation to `NULL`. On entry, also initialise the pointer to `NULL`. Then on exit (a valid use of `goto`), you can simply check the pointer against `NULL`, and if it is not null, `free()` it. (In fact once you get really cocky, you will know `free()` on `NULL` on most platforms is a no-op, so you can unconditionally free it). The setting the pointer to `NULL` bit is to avoid a double free.
2. This is the difference between the stack and the heap. Local variables are allocated on the stack. C destroys them automatically when a function returns. This is one of the few bits of magic C does. Note that I said it destroys the variables, not the things they point to. So if you have a pointer to allocated (heap) memory in a local variable, and the function returns, it will 'free' the variable (in the sense it will no longer be on the stack), but the allocated (heap) memory will not be freed. This is why you must free heap allocated memory only referenced in a function before the pointers to it are destroyed by exiting the function - see the answer to 1 above.
3. You don't need to free anything in `main()` in your example. If you had coded your function to return a pointer to memory on the heap (for instance if you'd coded the equivalent of `strdup()`) then your `main()` function would need to `free()` that. That brings up the important point that what the caller needs to `free()` depends on how the called function is designed. It's thus important that the called function makes this obvious in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I have to free the arrays that I have allocated dynamically in str_index?

Just before the `return;` statement of your function `str_index`.

> Do we have to free them within the function str_index?

Not necessary. Depends on the program requirement.

> What I know is that when a function is done executing all local variables are destroyed.

Yes, it is true for space allocated on stack (if variable is not `static`), but not for the space allocated on heap.

> Why do we have to free them in main?

Not necessary that it have to `free` in `main`. Depends on the program requirement.

Comment: What do you mean, by the program requirement?

Comment: If you are returning a pointer from your function, then this pointer should not be freed in that function. You should free that pointer in `main`. If function does't return pointer then it should be freed in that function.